# What is required to believe one is not a Situationist?

Tags: modal-logic

It has been somewhat humorously claimed that

> No person who calls themselves a [Situationist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Situationism) is!

If I think about this informally for a second, it would seem to reason that anyone who believes this claim must believe they are not a Situationist.  If we take a little liberty putting this in a modal logic where this can be written as

$\square(\square p \rightarrow \neg p) \rightarrow \square\neg p$

Where $p$ stands in for the arbitrary claim $\text{I am a Situationist}$.  And $\square$ is the [Doxastic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxastic_logic) modal meaning $\text{I believe}$  Although at this point what $p$ represents is no longer relevant and we can move beyond the framing to just talk about the logic.

This surprisingly looks a lot like [Löb's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6b%27s_theorem):

$\square(\square p \rightarrow p) \rightarrow \square p$

Which a modest reasoner should believe.

Now since this theorem seems reasonable and has a passing resemblance to an important theorem I thought I would try to prove it, and see what sort of reasoning is required to believe this claim.

However I can't seem to arrive at this no matter even with some strong axioms, such as a [Type G reasoner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxastic_logic#Increasing_levels_of_rationality).  I am starting to wonder if maybe my naïve reasoning is not so great, that this statement might not be provable for Type G reasoners or even inconsistent.

What is required to prove this?  Is it a consistent statement with a Type G reasoner?

Comment: Why put a link of situationist? It's not relevant watsoever. That's like saying "we have three apples" and you link the wiki page to "apple".

Comment: @Garmekain You can remove it if you want.  I figure some people don't know what a Situationist is and might want to know.  I was hoping it would stave off irrelevant questions, but it looks like it failed at that.

Comment: Indeed, it would be more useful to give a link to *Löb's theorem* or to *Type G reasoner*, as I doubt these notions are familiar to most readers on this site.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin I went ahead and added those links.

Comment: Thanks a lot...